# LINQ: Get last record where value is not null and divide the value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime

This is a piece of my table with relevant info

```
-------------------------
|   COL1   |     Id     |
-------------------------
|    20    | 25-01-2014 |
-------------------------
```

Now to the question:
I'm struggling with a LINQ statement that should get the last record where a column (COL1) has a value that is different from 0.0 (Zero). Then I need to find the amount of days between the date in the Id column and today and then divide the value in COL1 with the amount of days.

Now to make things extra fun (sorry for the sarcasms), I'm in the situation where COL1 could have multiple values on the same day like this:

```
-------------------------
|   COL1   |     Id     |
-------------------------
|    20    | 25-01-2014 |
-------------------------
|    25    | 25-01-2014 |
-------------------------
```

In this case I would have to get the sum of those values for that day and divide that result with the amount of days from, in this case 25-01-2014, until today.

I hope someone will be able to help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you're going to want to tackle that whole process with one Linq query.  Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: I hate to answer those type of questions: Create class definitions, create sample data, test it and then post an answer. (Of course OP is to busy too prepare those data :) )

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

```
var data; // this should be wherever you get your data from.

var lastGroup = data.GroupBy(item => item.Id).OrderBy(group => group.Key).Last();
var date = lastGroup.Key;
var sum = lastGroup.Sum();
var result = sum / (DateTime.Today - date).TotalDays
```